# Is there any way to have a windows installation like docker?

Tags: windows-10, docker

For example I would like to have a windows 10 installation that is described in a file.

So every time I want to re-install windows I don't need to re-install and configure all my apps.

Comment: You can do that with Azure, and probably with VMWare, but like with Docker, this relies on some kind of virtualization system that can act as the installing agent. Otherwise on bare-metal, your best bet is Imaging, sysprep for unattended solutions, or using MS server infrastructure to push down configuration (GPO, SCCM, etc).

Answer (score 0):

1. **OPTION 1**

The Microsoft solution to this is native booting a VHD. The idea here is that you can apply a WIM image to a VHD and then add a BCDBoot menu item for the VHD. Once you have done that you can make a copy of the VHD and keep it for whenever you want to return to that state. You could have many of them and choose which one to boot from the Windows bootloader menu.

DETAILED INSTRUCTIONS AVAILABLE FROM MICROSOFT:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu

You can move these VHD to any PC or VM. This allows you to use bare metal and virutal computers with the same virtual hard drive.

2. **OPTION 2**

What you are talking about reminds me of Puppet:
https://puppet.com/

They aim to make "Code based configurations" where you maintain your settings like a developer would maintain code. This way, they say you don't need system backups because all of your settings are deployed and maintained by the puppetmaster.

That being said, this solution is not simple at all.